# Why are there so many ". mount" files in the cgroup path "/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice"?

Tags: docker, systemd, cgroups

Why are there so many. mount files in the cgroup path?

i checked systemd config but get nothing to do

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMpF6.jpg)

Comment: Based on the filenames, I'd wager they're related to docker containers, either currently running or previously running.

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about writing code, not using or understanding your Linux system. That said, did you read the systemd mount unit documentation?

Comment: Also, note that questions need to include enough information to be answerable _in the text of the question itself_. Screenshots and links don't count for the reasons given in [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)